# Outlook calendar invites sent from GMail account

Tags: iphone, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2003, google-calendar

I use Outlook 2003 at work (on windows XP) and sync my Outlook calendar with my Google calendar using [iCal4OL](http://ical.gutentag.ch/). I access my Google calendar from various places, home (Windows 7), work and also from my iPhone, which has both calendars on. That's been working fine for some time.

However, recently people at work have started receiving meeting invites for recurring meetings (for which I'm not the organiser), and these meeting invites originate from my GMail account. It's obviously very awkward and I have apologised profusely to the people concerned, but I would like to stop it from happening again. I have noticed this morning that the meetings seem to be sent 15 min before the meeting is to take place, which seems to coincide with the Outlook reminder. There is no trace of any meeting requests being sent in my GMail Sent Items folder, and yet people are receiving. I have been in touch with the people at iCal4OL and it doesn't seem to be an issue with the sync'ing. In fact, the latest set of invites were sent before I had started running the sync'ing program in the background.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what to do to stop this from happening again. Can anybody suggest anything? I've searched for similar issues on Google, but nothing came up.

Comment: Were these people originally invited to these events and your talking about secondary invites?

Comment: Yes, there were people originally invited. It's as if Google or iPhone (not sure which) has taken ownership of the meeting and sent an updated meeting request

Comment: Have you tried marking these events on the Google calendar as private and removing the invitation list?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll try but the events originate in my Outlook, where I'm invited to them, and then get synced to my Google calendar. So any manual changes I make now on existing events may not work as a long-term solution for future events.

Comment: We are going to try a few things get somebody to help you, send an Outlook Calendar invite to them, and test to see if Google Calendar then sends out invites.  We will have to come up with a solution to mark these events as private ( i suspect them being public is the problem ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the upload of attendees in iCal4OL- and it will not happen anymore.
Please see about this issue here (updated page): 
http://ical.gutentag.ch/Outlook-Google-Synchronization%20by%20iCal4OL.html

Comment: Can you summarize that link, so that if it goes dead, the answer is still useful?

Comment: @Ramhound thank you both, I have both marked the events as private and also suppressed the upload of attendees in iCal4OL, will keep an eye and see if the problem happens again